# Why's my GET request becoming unidentifiable?

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, debugging, get

I want to eventually call functions from my php file onto my reactjs project so just to scratch the surface, I'm trying to to do a basic get request, but in the console, all I see is:

```
Here's it is [object Response]
```

Which isn't what I want to happen.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Here's my js code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Home extends Component {

    componentWillMount() {
        fetch("http://localhost/myProject/phpCalls/index.php", {
            method: 'GET'
        })
            .then(res => {
                console.log("Here's it is " + res);
            });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <h1>testing</h1>
        );
    }
}

export default Home;
```

Here's my php file:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');

function hey() {
    echo "Will I see this?";
}

$test = $_GET['do'];

if($test === "hey") {
    hey();
}
```

Comment: `fetch` returns a `Promise` that resolves to a `Response` object, it doesn't resolve to text, see docs, use `.text()` or the appropriate method

Comment: @CertainPerformance I've used `.text()` and `.json()` but they both don't work hence why I asked this question.

Comment: Your PHP also requires on `$_GET['do'] === "hey"` but your request doesn't contain anything like that

Comment: @CertainPerformance not sure what you mean by requires on `$_GET['do'] === "hey"`.  Apologies in advance, my new to backend work, I'm just trying to get my feet wet with all this.  may you please provide an example that pertains my scenario?

Comment: console.log("Here's it is " , res);

Comment: @Kurohige I tried that a while ago, it doesn't work.

Comment: You need to see what is exactly returned by your PHP API, run the application in your browser and open inspect, then go to network tab and see the request you are sending and what's in its response